# Taking floor of keys and average of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks something like this:

```
{0.234 : 100, 0.345 : 120, 2.45: 200, 2.55 : 250}
```

For my problem I have to take the `floor()` of the keys and take average of corresponding values.

```
{0 : 110, 2 : 225}
```

How should I go about it? I was thinking of maybe appending values with the same floor value of the key to list and then taking average of all lists :

```
{ 0 : [100, 120], 2 : [200, 250]}
```

But I cannot figure how to do that either.

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out how to do it? What have you tried? Have you read the documentation relating to dictionaries and lists?

Comment: Homework? I would probably do with with list comprehensions and/or dictionary comprehensions. I don't want to code it for you if it's homework, though. You wouldn't learn that way.

Comment: @johnrsharpe .I saw a few similar questions on stackoverflow but they were about grouping keys together in lists. I haven't gone through documentation of dictionaries and lists. I am doing it right now since you're suggesting I might find something useful for this.

Comment: @TomZych No its not homework. Its for a school project I have a dictionary of timestamps and frequencies. I am trying to apply a formula to convert timestamps to ticks for a midi file.

Comment: School project...homework...I see little difference. In any case, you should most certainly read the docs and try to solve it yourself before posting here. This site is for specific answers to specific questions. It is not for throwing up one's hands helplessly and asking others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` is used to collect the values based on a common key, which is the floor value of the keys in the original dict.

```
import math
from collections import defaultdict

original_dict = {0.234 : 100, 0.345 : 120, 2.45: 200, 2.55 : 250}
d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in original_dict.iteritems(): # or .items() if you are on Python 3.x
     d[math.floor(k)].append(v)

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] = sum(v)/len(v)

print(d)
```

Comment: Note: in python3.4+ you should use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) instead of rolling an home-made mean implementation that will fail in most edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
a = {0.234 : 100, 0.345 : 120, 2.45: 200, 2.55 : 250}
d = {}
for x in a:
    if (math.floor(x)) not in d:
        d[math.floor(x)] = [a[x]]
    else:
        d[math.floor(x)] += [a[x]]
```

Output of `d`:

```
{ 0 : [100, 120], 2 : [200, 250]}
```

Then:

```
for x in d:
    d[x] = sum(d[x]) // len(d[x])
```

Output of `d`:

```
{0 : 110, 2 : 225}
```